# How to combine collection of linq queries into a single sql request

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

Thanks for checking this out.

My situation is that I have a system where the user can create custom filtered views which I build into a linq query on the request.  On the interface they want to see the counts of all the views they have created; pretty straight forward.  I'm familiar with combining multiple queries into a single call but in this case I don't know how many queries I have initially.

Does anyone know of a technique where this loop combines the count queries into a single query that I can then execute with a ToList() or FirstOrDefault()?

```
//TODO Performance this isn't good...
foreach (IMeetingViewDetail view in currentViews)
{
    view.RecordCount = GetViewSpecificQuery(view.CustomFilters).Count();
}
```

Here is an example of multiple queries combined as I'm referring to.  This is two queries which I then combine into an anonymous projection resulting in a single request to the sql server.

```
 IQueryable<EventType> eventTypes = _eventTypeService.GetRecords().AreActive<EventType>();
            IQueryable<EventPreferredSetup> preferredSetupTypes = _eventPreferredSetupService.GetRecords().AreActive<EventPreferredSetup>();

            var options = someBaseQuery.Select(x => new
                {
                    EventTypes = eventTypes.AsEnumerable(),
                    PreferredSetupTypes = preferredSetupTypes.AsEnumerable()
                }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "combine?"

Comment: I mean combine the IQueryable<>s.  Pretend I took the Count() off the query, then I would just have an IQueryable which I could then combine into a single projection which results in a single query.  In this case I don't know how many queryables I'll end up with because it's one per user created record.

Comment: You'll end up with *one.*  IQueryable is lazy; you can chain IQueryables, and the combined Linq statement won't execute until you force it to provide output by calling something like Count or ToList.  Chaining IQueryables creates an execution pipeline.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx

Comment: No, I end up with one query per count.  I added an example to the question.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.  `Count()` forces an execution of the processing pipeline.

Comment: I understand that, my question is how/if possible to combine them into one execution.

Comment: I don't see how.  `Count()` is an `O(n)` operation; you have to enumerate each collection to find out how many items are in it.

Comment: Sure, but if I have two collections and I know I have two collections then they could both be put into a single data projection which would result in one sql query for both counts.  For example if the user always had 5 views I could get all 5 with one data projection, but since I don't know how many there are I need something dynamic.

Comment: Can you UNION the two collections together before taking the Count()?

Comment: I think that would require I return the entities themselves in a collection which are too large, I really need the efficiency of the database doing the count.  I can't bring back all the meetings for each view.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for performance considerations, I would change the interface from `IEnumerable<T>` to a collection that has a Count property. Both `IList<T>` and `ICollection<T>` have a count property.
This way, the collection object is keeping track of its size and you just need to read it.

If you really wanted to avoid the loop, you could redefine the RecordCount to be a lazy loaded integer that calls GetViewSpecificQuery to get the count once.

```
private int? _recordCount = null;
public int RecordCount 
{
    get 
    {
         if (_recordCount == null)
             _recordCount = GetViewSpecificQuery(view.CustomFilters).Count;
         return _recordCount.Value;
    }
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything.  I still have multiple user views to get the count for, lazy loading them is still a sql request per count.